# How to get parent block device belonging to a given partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning

Let's say I've got partition /dev/sdc1, how do I get the parent block device the partition belongs to (in this case /dev/sdc) ?

Preferably in bash or C.

Something along the way of lsblk output:

```
~:lsblk /dev/sdc
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc      8:32   1   7.4G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   7.4G  0 part
```

But in reverse, that is, I need it to return the exact same full block device tree, when I issue something like:

```
lsblk /dev/sdc1
```

Notice partition 1 in the block device name. When I use the command, all I get is just partition listing:

```
~:lsblk /dev/sdc1
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc1   8:33   1   7.4G  0 part
```

And this is not what I need.

Comment: You could inspect the device node for major and minor number, the “parent” is at minor number `0`. But I don’t know how reliable that is, so I’m not posting it as an answer for the time being.

Comment: You just need something that returns /dev/sdc when you give it the input of /dev/sdc1 ?

Comment: Yes, I need /dev/sdc as output whenever I query /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdc4, etc. I tried minor number inspection, but it's not reliable: parent block device is not always 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226420/how-to-get-disk-name-that-contains-a-specific-partition), including lsblk or sysfs inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the parent block device as follows:

```
basename `readlink -f "/sys/class/block/sdc1/.."`
```